# Usage of mysql variables in query in Spring Jdbc Template gives error

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring, jdbc

I have a requirement of picking top 2 students within each subject. Here is my table and the query which I am using to get that.

```
CREATE TABLE `students` (               
`student` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,   
`subject` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,   
`marks` int(10) DEFAULT NULL          
);

INSERT INTO students VALUES
('Deepak', 'Maths', 100),
('Neha', 'Maths', 90),
('Jyoti', 'Maths', 80),
('Ashwini', 'Maths', 70),
('Amit', 'Maths', 30),
('Sandeep', 'Maths', 95),
('Cinni', 'Maths', 86),
('Anand', 'Maths', 75),
('Deepak', 'Science', 100),
('Neha', 'Science', 90),
('Jyoti', 'Science', 80),
('Ashwini', 'Science', 70),
('Amit', 'Science', 30),
('Sandeep', 'Science', 95),
('Cinni', 'Science', 86),
('Anand', 'Science', 75),
('Deepak', 'History', 100),
('Neha', 'History', 90),
('Jyoti', 'History', 80),
('Ashwini', 'History', 70),
('Amit', 'History', 30),
('Sandeep', 'History', 95),
('Cinni', 'History', 86),
('Anand', 'History', 75);



mysql> SELECT * FROM students
+---------+---------+-------+
| student | subject | marks |
+---------+---------+-------+
| Deepak  | Maths   |   100 |
| Neha    | Maths   |    90 |
| Jyoti   | Maths   |    80 |
| Ashwini | Maths   |    70 |
| Amit    | Maths   |    30 |
| Sandeep | Maths   |    95 |
| Cinni   | Maths   |    86 |
| Anand   | Maths   |    75 |
| Deepak  | Science |   100 |
| Neha    | Science |    90 |
| Jyoti   | Science |    80 |
| Ashwini | Science |    70 |
| Amit    | Science |    30 |
| Sandeep | Science |    95 |
| Cinni   | Science |    86 |
| Anand   | Science |    75 |
| Deepak  | History |   100 |
| Neha    | History |    90 |
| Jyoti   | History |    80 |
| Ashwini | History |    70 |
| Amit    | History |    30 |
| Sandeep | History |    95 |
| Cinni   | History |    86 |
| Anand   | History |    75 |
+---------+---------+-------+
24 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> Set character_set_connection=latin1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> Set character_set_results=latin1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> Set character_set_client=latin1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @rowcnt := 0; SET @grp := ''; SELECT d.* FROM (
    ->     SELECT
    ->         cs.*,
    ->         @rowcnt := IF(@grp != cs.subject, 1, @rowcnt + 1) AS rowcnt,
    ->         @grp := cs.subject
    ->     FROM (
    ->         SELECT * FROM students ORDER BY subject, marks DESC
    ->     ) cs
    -> ) d
    -> WHERE d.rowcnt < 3;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

+---------+---------+-------+--------+--------------------+
| student | subject | marks | rowcnt | @grp := cs.subject |
+---------+---------+-------+--------+--------------------+
| Deepak  | History |   100 |      1 | History            |
| Sandeep | History |    95 |      2 | History            |
| Deepak  | Maths   |   100 |      1 | Maths              |
| Sandeep | Maths   |    95 |      2 | Maths              |
| Deepak  | Science |   100 |      1 | Science            |
| Sandeep | Science |    95 |      2 | Science            |
+---------+---------+-------+--------+--------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Now, everything works fine from the console, but when I execute the same query in Spring JdbcTemplate, it gives me error.

```
jdbcTemplate.query(query, new StudentRowMapper());
```

The query prints out to following which is exactly same as the query which I am using on command line.

```
SET @rowcnt := 0; SET @grp := ''; SELECT d.* FROM ( SELECT cs.*, @rowcnt := IF(@grp != cs.subject, 1, @rowcnt + 1) AS rowcnt, @grp := cs.subject FROM ( SELECT * FROM students ORDER BY subject, marks DESC ) cs ) d WHERE d.rowcnt < 3;
```

Here is the error which I get while running this:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @grp := ''; SELECT d.* FROM ( SELECT cs.*, ' at line 1
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4190)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4122)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2570)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2731)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2818)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2157)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2324)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:646)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:589)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:639)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:668)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:676)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:716)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just place the vars in the select like this

```
SELECT d.* 
FROM 
    ( SELECT cs.*, @rowcnt := IF(@grp != cs.subject, 1, @rowcnt + 1) AS rowcnt, @grp := cs.subject 
     FROM ( SELECT * FROM (select @rowcnt :=0, @grp :='') a,students ORDER BY subject, marks DESC ) cs ) d 
WHERE d.rowcnt < 3;
```

Comment: This doesnt' show any error, but also no data is returned.